# Output oversize 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm doing an assignment (no I'm not asking you guys to do it for me I just need help with a small part)
Basically I have an oversize 2D array that needs to be outputed when the user chooses.
I'll include all of my code so far but be warned, it's too long. I would appreciate any help, thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class customerDatabase {

    public static Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
        Scanner inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
        char choice = 'z';
        int i = 0;
        String[][] customerInfo = new String[100][5];
        int arrayLength = 0;

        while(inFS.hasNext()){
            customerInfo[i][0]=inFS.next(); //first name
            customerInfo[i][1]=inFS.next(); //last name
            customerInfo[i][2]=inFS.next(); //email
            customerInfo[i][3]=inFS.nextLine(); //phone number
            ++i;
            ++arrayLength;
        }

        while(choice != 'q'){
            choice = printMenu();
        }if(choice == 'o'){
            outputDatabase(customerInfo,arrayLength);
        }


    }

    public static char printMenu(){

        char userChar = 'z';
        String choiceString;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("o - Output customer database");
        System.out.println("s - Sort by name");
        System.out.println("a - Add a customer");
        System.out.println("r - Remove a customer");
        System.out.println("u - Update customer information");
        System.out.println("f - Find a customer");
        System.out.println("q - Quit");
        System.out.println();

        while((userChar != 'o') && (userChar != 's') && (userChar!= 'a') && (userChar != 'r') && (userChar != 'u') &&(userChar != 'f') && (userChar!= 'q')){
            System.out.println("Choose an option:");
            choiceString = scnr.nextLine();
            userChar = choiceString.charAt(0);
        }

        return userChar;

    }

    public static void outputDatabase(String[][] userArray, int arraySize){
        int i;
        int j;

        for(i=0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
            for(j=0; j < arraySize; ++j) {
                System.out.print(userArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then there's a text file which includes names and emails and phone numbers (which is what is being inserted into the array that is being output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I have an oversize 2d array that needs to be output when the
>   user chooses for it to be.

You have four properties i.e. **First Name, Last Name, Email & Phone Number** and hence, your inner loop should only go from index zero to index three,

```
for(int i=0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
    for(int j=0; j < 4; ++j) {
        System.out.print(userArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Currently, you are setting it to `arraySize` which will result in an exception if `arraySize` is greater than four.